# TWRP exclude files from backup

Tags: backup, twrp, encryption

I'm trying to make a TWRP backup, but I'm getting an error because of encrypted files. The files are in /data/misc/bluedroid, but I don't really care about bluetooth (though if I can keep it, that would be a nice bonus.) I thought of pulling the files onto my laptop as a backup then deleting them on the phone so that the backup can proceed, but `adb pull` can't access the files either.

Is there a way to tell TWRP to skip those files?

The phone is an Honor 7x BND-L24 with TWRP 3.1.1-1.

Comment: Usually TWRP will backup the encrypted files without any problems because it doesn't actually require access to the files contents. Think of it as binary copies, The file is actually a series of 10101's that can be replicated without any access to the files contents, Like copy and pasting a password protected ZIP File, The contents of the ZIP are encrypted and inaccessible however the entire file is still movable because it's not actually trying to read the file but move it to a new location.  I'm not sure why your TWRP cannot copy encrypted files unless it's trying to calculate the contents

Comment: @Zillinium: That's what I would have assumed, but adb has the same problem: unencrypted files work fine, but encrypted ones say something about not having the key, so I'm quite sure the encryption is the problem.

Comment: Is it possible that it's trying to compress the file ? that'd cause an issue if it can't read the file contents.... Are you looking to make a backup of your system, or just user data... Maybe choosing to skip the entire data partition could work, the data partition is reformatted on a factory reset anyway, so the bluedroid file should be recreated upon resetting the device.